Is this Cat5 or Cat5e?
I purchased some FTP cable and checked it when I got home. It's labeled as Cat5 on the cable. After returning to the store, the employee showed me the box, which stated Category 5e. They also showed me other boxes where it said Category 5e, but the cable inside was labeled as Cat5. So, which label accurately describes the cable?Box image
Cable image

I'd say only the manufacturer would be able to answer that.

It's CAT5e. CAT5e was established as a standard 23 years, replacing CAT5.

if you are unsure, don't buy cat 5,use cat 6 or 7 patch cables there's no updated replacement

The original Cat-5 specifications somewhat neglected near-end crosstalk which became much more relevant with 1000BASE-T (IEEE 802.3ab-1999) than with the slower two-pair variants. The revised spec was called Cat 5e. Subsequently, ISO/IEC 11801 und EN 50173 2002/2003 just called it Cat 5 again.
So, unless you've got really old cabling (from before 2002 or so), "Cat 5" and "Cat 5e" are the exact same thing.

Thanks! The date labeled on it is 21.09.23. So, could it provide up to 2.5 Gbps?

Yes, by spec it should be good for 2.5GBASE-T over up to 100 m - as always, with up to 90 m solid-core and up to 10 m flexible, stranded cable.
